# custom-unique Field with relation to ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models

let's start with the model

```
#models.py
class Project(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Issue(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.ForeignKey('Status')


class Status(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=10, help_text=u'eg open, closed...')
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    project = models.ManyToManyField(Project)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.default:
            #self.__class__.objects.filter(default=True, project=self.project).update(default=False)
            pass
```

I'd like to set all `default` to `False` when a user selects on another `Status` the `default` option. How could I achieve this?

**Edit:**

A user will be able to create custom `Status` for his project. So, let's say the user got 2 Projects - they are called **Audi** and **BMW**.

Now the user creates a `Status` for an `Issue`. It's name will be `open` and he selects it to be default for all `Issues` within the `Project` **BMW**.
All issues within the project **BMW** will get the default status `open`. Great!

Now the user creates another `Status` for an `Issue`. This time the name will be `new` and he selects it to be default for **all his Projects**!

So, what I need is something (with as less queries as possible) that sets the first Status `open` within **BMW** to `default = false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.default:
            for status in Status.objects.filter(default=True,project__in=self.project.all()):
                status.default=False
                status.save()
        super(Status,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a single-instance Settings model with a `ForeignKey` `Status` relationship:

```
class Settings(models.Model):
    default_status = models.ForeignKey('Status')
```

You may want to [enforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138408/limit-number-of-model-instances-to-be-created-django) there only being one `Settings` instance.

Alternatively, you could perform the un-defaulting in save():

```
if self.default:
    for status in self.__class__.objects.all():
        if status != self:
            status.default = False
            status.save()
```

Note that if you're overriding `Model.save()`, you'll want to use `super()` to re-instate the original behaviour of that function. See [Overriding predefined model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) in the Django documentation.

Comment: A good idea with a settings-model, thank you. But I'd love to keep my first draft because there are some more models with a similar structure.

Comment: Another suggestion has been added.

Comment: Still got the problem with the projects. I've extended my question, maybe you got an idea?

Comment: schacki's answer adds the necessary filter. I'm not convinced it won't set `self.default` to `False` under certain conditions, though. The more you describe this state management problem, the more I feel you should be using a `Settings` model — it would be extensible, terse and prevent all this unnecessary traversal. What, for instance, would happen if someone created an issue while the default was in the process of being changed and either 0 or >1 `State`s were currently default?

Comment: Hh, that's a realy good point to think about. Damn...need to reconcept it :( thank you! :)

Comment: You also gain adherence to [DRY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-repeat-yourself-dry), which comes with its own benefits.