# Django: How to access instance of a model directly from admin index

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd like to have a preferences app with just one instance containing some global settings eg.

```
# preferences/models.py
class Preferences(models.Model):
    site_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    site_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="logo", null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if Preferences.objects.count() > 1:
            return
        super(Preferences, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Credits for the save override: this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2138495/1344854).
Also, I have removed add button, again thanks to the aforementioned [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12469482/1344854)

```
# preferences/admin.py
class PreferencesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        num_objects = self.model.objects.count()
        if num_objects >= 1:
            return False
        else:
            return True

admin.site.register(Preferences, PreferencesAdmin)
```

Now, all I want is to jump to the first and only instance of my Preferences model directly from admin index page. Any suggestions how could I achieve this? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an app to do just that: https://github.com/ionata/django-singletons
Just be sure to use a fork above, as original [singletons](https://github.com/tttallis/django-singletons) won't work with Django 1.5