# Django Global Site Configuration in Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to have a way for the content manager of the website I am developing to edit global settings in the admin part of a django application. With global settings, I mean something like: site title, twitter link, facebook link, banner, logo, etc...

Currently I have a `Settings` model for that, with all the fields I need. However, the way it is structured it is allowing me to have multiple Settings instance in the database, even though I just want one.

How can I force having only one instance of Settings, therefore bypassing this step of creating a Setting instance and going directly to the only one that matters?

Thanks.

P.S. I have also looked into the [django-settings module](https://github.com/jqb/django-settings), but that doesn't serve my purpose.

Comment: There's probably a bunch of hacks you can use for this, but the more fundamental fix would be to not use the django admin. It's specifically meant to be a CRUD interface for datasets... things with more than one record. I'd throw together a standalone page for this that always retrieves the same Settings instance via a hardcoded ID.

Comment: I get what you're saying.. I would like to keep the same interface though. Hence, looking for a solution within the django admin. Would you care to share some of the hacks you say there are? Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138408/limit-number-of-model-instances-to-be-created-django for a way of limiting yourself to a single instance of the settings model.

Comment: In my company, we have built something which solves exactly this issue. A web interface to modify django settings file. The person who had built this is not available right now, but there is this [blog](http://tech.goibibo.com/post/34690342727/how-a-python-a-penguin-and-a-dog-became-best-friends), which has all the details. Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Override the `ModelAdmin` for `Settings` to only fetch the one and only object is what I would do, it's a lot of code though.

Comment: Also have a look at `django-constance`, which we use for similar user-configurable site-wide settings.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to extend the Site model with an inline for your settings. You can limit the number of instances of the inline to one and only the site specified in settings.py will be loaded, effectively giving you a singleton on which to store "settings".