# Django - Limit the number of instances of a model for every user

Tags: django, validation, django-models

I want to limit the number of instances of a specific class. I already have limited it by using some HTML, but if someone sneaky reuses the link to the form, one can make another instance.

So in my **views.py**, I make a query

```
qry_models = Model.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
```

In my HTML-template, I already made the adjustments to prevent multiple instances. If there is none, one is redirected to the ModelForm to create an instance. If there is a model in the query, it is displayed/usable.

```
{% for model in qry_models %}
    {{ model }}
{% empty %}
    <a href="{% url 'app:model_new' %}">Make a new instance</a>
{% endfor %}
```

But if someone reuses the link one is redirected to in the first place, he can create another instance. That shall be prevented.

I want to have one instance for each user account. If I follow [Limit number of model instances to be created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138408/limit-number-of-model-instances-to-be-created-django), I always get a **MultipleObjectsReturned** error since it queries all instances from all account and not only the instances from the active/logged in account.

Edit:
I made another query that always redirects me, if there already is an instance. But is that good code-design or just a useful logic circle?

```
def model_new(request):
    mymodel = Model.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    counter = mymodel.count()
    if counter >0:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('somewhere')

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = ModelForm()
    ....
```

Comment: How can I prevent it in admin?

Comment: What does your model look like? I would suggest defining the `owner` field as a `OneToOneField` instead of a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: What's the limit? A single instance, or some other number?

Comment: Do you need to have only one related model for each user or different number for different users?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov OP says that "I want to have one instance for each user account."

Comment: Oh yeah, missed that. In that case — OneToOneField is the answer.

Comment: My model "teams" has just some fixed values and owner = models.ForeignKey(User). 
In my case, every user(account) has one Team (the model) that will have several fighters. But i want to prevent that one account can have multiple teams.

Answer (score 1):

Best practices of limiting the instances for a user in Django are mapping [one-to-one field relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) to user column in the table.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=100)

#Refactoring your views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse

def create_student(request):
    if not Student.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
        Student.objects.create(user=request.user, course='Engineering')
        return HttpResponse('Student is created')
   else:
       return HttpResponse('Student already exists')
```

Comment: If the requirement is one instance only, yes, this is the correct way.  But the title says "Limit the number of instances" doesn't say one