# Setting limit on models

Tags: python, django

How to set limits on models without using any package like django-limits, if the model limit is 4 then only 4 models could be created

Models

```
class Post(models.Model):

    #limit = 4

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138408/limit-number-of-model-instances-to-be-created-django).

```
def validate_under_four_instance(obj):
    model = obj.__class__
    if (model.objects.count() >= 4 and obj.pk not in model.objects.all().values_list('pk', flat=True)):
        raise ValidationError("Can only create under the 4 %s instances" % model.__name__)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    def clean(self):
        validate_under_four_instances(self)
```

Comment: I'm looking for more of a user-friendly solution, thx for your time tho!